# Disable `show code` button in Canvas storybook

Tags: reactjs, storybook

I use Canvas tag from storybook:

```
<Canvas>
  <Story name="Hello">
    {MyStory.bind({})}
  </Story>
</Canvas>
```

If i add this code in my `.mdx` file there appear the code source, but i want to disable the button that is responsible to show the source code.

Question: How to achieve what i described?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to remove the Canvas tag, it should most likely remove the `show code` button.